# Laravel 5.2 display single record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have downloaded a script written in Laravel i guess 5.2. I am having trouble showing single data in a row and column. It only shows the id but not the rest of the row. I have this code so far:

**search.blade.php**

```
<option value="">Search for...</option>
   @foreach(\App\SubCategories::orderBy('sub_category_name')->get() as $search_keyword) 
     <option value="{{$search_keyword->sub_category_slug}}">&nbsp;{{$search_keyword->sub_category_name}}</option> 
   @endforeach

<select id="location" name="location" class="form-control" required>
     <option value="">Select Location</option>
        @foreach(\App\Location::orderBy('location_name')->get() as $location) 
            <option value="{{$location->id}}">{{$location->location_name}}</option> 
        @endforeach
</select>
```

**ListingsUserController.php**

```
public function search_listings(Request $request)    
{ 

   $inputs = $request->all();

   $keyword = $inputs['search_keyword'];
   $location = $inputs['location'];

   $listings = Listings::SearchByKeyword($keyword,$location)->get();

   $total_res=count($listings);  

    return view('pages.search',compact('listings','total_res','keyword','location'));
}
```

**search.blade.php**

```
{{$total_res}} results for {{$keyword}}


{{$total_res}} results for {{$keyword}} in {{$location}}
```

I have added `{{$location}}` on the last line so I will display:

5 results for Keyword in Location

but it shows the id instead of location_name

5 results for Keyword in 10

I get an error if I put like this `{{$location->location_name}}`

I know this is so basic in Laravel but I am new to PHP Framework.

Anyone please?

Comment: You said "I get an error if I put like this {{$location->location_name}}" - Please provide a copy of the error.

Comment: It just says, OPS SOMETHING WENT WRONG

Answer (score 0):

`$location = $inputs['location'];` - This is just an ID being sent over from the server on form submission.

You need to load the model first, something like this should work:

```
$location = Location::find($inputs['location']);

$listings = Listings::SearchByKeyword($keyword,$location->id)->get();
```

Now things will work correctly for you as `$location` is an object with properties.

Comment: Is this in Location model or Listing model?

Comment: @JohnArzaga When I declare `$location = Location::find($inputs['location']);`, I retrieve a copy of the `Location` model. This is assuming you have a `Location` model.

Comment: Any other suggestions?